# Solve the exponential equation $2^x+3^{-x}+1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to solve the following exponential equation:

$$2^x+3^{-x}+1=0$$

To do so, this is what I do:

$$2^x+3^{-x}+1=0 \implies 2^x+\frac{1}{3^x}+1=0 \implies \frac{3^x\cdot2^x+1+3^x}{3^x} = 0$$

And then

$$6^x+1+3^x=0$$

And then I don't really know what to do next. I understand that I need to apply the logarithm at some point but I also think I need to have only two "terms", not three. Any hints?

The answer in my textbook is

$$x = \log_2{\frac{\sqrt{13}-1}{2}}$$

Comment: $3^x$ and $6^x$ only take positive values, so there is no solution in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This equation $$2^x+3^{-x}+1=0$$ has no real solution since left side is always positive.

---

If the commentator is correct, then just put $a=2^x$ and we get $a-{3\over a}+1=0$
so $a^2+a-3=0$ and thus $a={-1\pm \sqrt{13}\over 2}$. Since $a>0$ we have $$x=\log_2{-1+ \sqrt{13}\over 2}$$

Comment: Thanks, it's so weird my textbook reports that there is a solution.

Comment: Have you write it down correctly?

Comment: Yes, double checked. But your answer obviously makes sense, thanks!

Comment: The textbook-provided solution is the solution to: $$2^x-3(2^{-x})+1=0$$ ... perhaps just a bad edit?

Answer (score 2):

We can guess that the correct equation is
$$2^x-3\cdot2^{-x}+1=0.$$

Then with $z:=2^x$,

$$z-3z^{-1}+1=0$$ or

$$z^2+z-3=0$$

has the roots

$$z=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{13}}2,$$

i.e. as $z$ must be positive,

$$x=\log_2\frac{-1+\sqrt{13}}2.$$